# How to calculate the number of tasks created by an openMP program.?

Tags: task, openmp

I am looking to find the number of tasks. How to get the number of tasks created by the openMP program ?

```
void quicksort(int* A,int left,int right)
{

    int i,last;

    if(left>=right)
        return;

    swap(A,left,(left+right)/2);

    last=left;

    for(i=left+1;i<=right;i++)
        if(A[i] < A[left])
            swap(A,++last,i);
    swap(A,left,last);

    #pragma omp task
    quicksort(A,left,last-1);

    quicksort(A,last+1,right);

    #pragma omp taskwait

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to gain an insight in what your OpenMP program is doing, you should use a OpenMP-task-aware performance analysis tool. For example [Score-P](https://score-p.org) can record all task operations in either a trace with full timing information or a summary profile. There are then several other tools to analyse and visualize the recorded information.

Take a look at this paper for more information for [performance analysis of task-based OpenMP applications](http://apps.fz-juelich.de/jsc-pubsystem/aigaion/attachments/schmidl_iwomp2012.pdf-5d909613b453c6fdbf34af237b8d5e52.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way of counting the number of OpenMP tasks, as OpenMP does not offer any way to actually query how many tasks have been created thus far.  The OpenMP runtime system may or may not keep track of this number, so it would unfair (and would have performance implications) if such a number would be kept in a runtime that is otherwise not interested in this number.

**The following is a terrible hack! Be sure you absolutely want to do this!**
Having said the above, you can do the count manually.  Assuming that your code is deterministically creating the same number of tasks for each execution, you can do this:

```
int tasks_created;
void quicksort(int* A,int left,int right)
{

    int i,last;

    if(left>=right)
        return;

    swap(A,left,(left+right)/2);

    last=left;

    for(i=left+1;i<=right;i++)
        if(A[i] < A[left])
            swap(A,++last,i);
    swap(A,left,last);

    #pragma omp task
    {
        #pragma omp atomic
        tasks_created++

        quicksort(A,left,last-1);
    }

    quicksort(A,last+1,right);

    #pragma omp taskwait

}
```

I'm saying that this is a terrible hack, because

- it requires you to find all the task-creating statements to modify them with the `atomic` construct and the increment
- it does not work well for some task-generating directives, e.g., `taskloop`
- it may horribly slow down execution, so that you cannot leave the modification in for production (that's the part abut determinism, you need run once with the count and then remove the counting for production)

**Another way...**
If you are using a reasonably new implementation of OpenMP that already supports the new OpenMP tools interfaces of OpenMP 5.0, you can write a small tool that hooks into the OpenMP events for task-creation.  Then you can do the count in the tool and attach it to our execution through the OpenMP tools mechanism.